# How to know the number of beta users of my app?

Tags: apk, google-play

Google Play Developer Console allows developers to [upload a beta APK](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en), and invite a Google Group to use it.

How to know how many users are using my beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Play Developer Console has changed a lot since the original answer.

If you are using Open Beta Testing then go to:

**Release Management / App Releases / Manage Beta**

and you will see something like this:

[image]

Note: if the number of testers is not showing, this might be because the number has not yet reached a certain threshold.

This specifically answers the question "How many people have opted into Beta testing?" which may or may not be what the OP was really interested in.

Analytics would be the way to discover how many are actually using the beta version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update! My very strict privacy policy forbids me from collecting analytics, so your answer is the best available option to me.

Answer (score 3):

In the console:

- Go to `Statistics`,
- Click `Export as CSV`,
- Uncheck everything but `Installs devices current` and `by app version`
- In the resulting CSV, spot the id of the APK you sent for beta
- The number in the third column is the number of beta users.