# How to get the number of beta users for a Google Play app

Tags: android, google-play, release-management, beta-testing, google-developers-console

In this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985497/how-to-know-the-number-of-beta-users-of-my-app), we are advised to take action no longer available in the `Google Play Developer Console`.  There is now a `Download` link that provides a zip file that includes a csv ending in `app_version', but since I have promoted the beta code to production, both the production and beta users will be running the same version.  Thus, the beta testers can not be divined from the version of the app.

When beta users go to the Play Store, they are informed that they are a beta tester, and given the option to opt-out of being a beta tester any longer.

Optimally, I'd like to know how many people would get the *you are a beta tester* message if they looked in the Play Store.

EDIT TO ADD 2021 10 25: My Google Play Console does not show the count:

[image: Google Play Console Not Showing Count of Beta Users]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Open Testing and you will find the number here (see the image below)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If the words in the red box not appears in my console, is that mean there is no users in the beta track?